# Routing to deep nested component Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have a route like this:

```ts
{
    path: 'parent',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: ParentComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'child1',
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':childID',
                    component: Child1Component
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'child2',
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':childID',
                    component: Child2Component
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to call route for child1/childID. How do I route to it?

Right now I use this:

```ts
this._router.navigate(["child1", auction_ID]);
```

but it does not routes back to parent

Comment: *"but it does not routes back to parent"* If you want to go from child to parent, you should do something like this: `this._router.navigate(["/parent"]):`

Comment: If you want to navigate to the child route you'll need to `navigate(["parent", "child1", auction_ID])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start at the "top" when you are navigating to a certain route. In your case, you want to go to `parent -> child1 -> :childID` so you have to pass all those parts in the `navigate` method.

**Navigate to the Child**

```ts
this._router.navigate(['parent', 'child1', auction_ID]);
```

**Navigate to the Parent**

```ts
this._router.navigate(['parent']);
```